# Is acknowledgement critical in TWS c++ API

Tags: c++, sockets, event-driven, interactive-brokers

### My question

In the Interactive Brokers TWS c++ API, (or in event-driven programming in general) when is it critical to change the state/mode (this is `m_state` in TWS API) to a state of "acknowledgement?" Depending on the state of this variable, different class methods are called. Towards the end of the definition of one of these methods, the state is changed back to an acknowledgement state, which appears to allow messages to be received by the host. Can I change `m_state` to something else, and skip the acknowledgement process altogether?

### Some background information for those who don't know the TWS API

#### (feel free to ignore this section)

Interactive Brokers' TWS C++ API has tens of thousands of lines of code, so let me try to describe what I think the essential functionality is.

My programs entry point in `Main.cpp` instantiates a client object, and then repeatedly calls its `void TestCppClient::processMessages()` method over and over again in every iteration of a while loop.

On the one hand, there are a bunch of methods that get triggered by the broker whenever the broker decides to call them, and you, as a client, may or may not take advantage of the provided information.

But on the other hand, there are a bunch of methods that get triggered by my client code. Depending on the value of `m_state`, a different class method is triggered. In the sample code provided by IB, that is, in my `TestCppClient` class, most of these functions have some helpful demonstration code provided, and more to the point of my question, most of these functions have the last line setting the value of `m_state` to something ending in `_ACK` (which, I believe, is a socket programming convention that is short for "acknowledgement.")

For example, when `m_state` is equal to `ST_REUTERSFUNDAMENTALS`, `TestCppClient::processMessages()`'s `switch` statement will trigger `TestCppClient::reutersFundamentals()`. The last line of this method's definition is

```
m_state = ST_REUTERSFUNDAMENTALS_ACK;
```

The next time `void TestCppClient::processMessages()` is triggered, (and it gets triggered all the time by the while loop, if you recall) the switch statement is skipped due to there only being a `break` statement:

```
...
case ST_REUTERSFUNDAMENTALS:
    reutersFundamentals();
    break;
case ST_REUTERSFUNDAMENTALS_ACK:
    break;
...
```

This switch statement code makes up the majority of the code in this function's definition, but there is a little at the end outside of the switch statement. The only code that runs in `TestCppClient::procesMessages()` in this case is at the very end, which is

```
m_pReader->checkClient();
m_osSignal.waitForSignal();
m_pReader->processMsgs();
```

These lines apparently handle some low-level socket programming stuff.

### Reiterating my question

So, if I didn't change the state to an acknowledgement state, these last three lines wouldn't run. But would that be a bad thing? Does anyone have experience with this? Any anecdotal pieces of information?

Comment: How do you change `m_state` in your code? In `TestCppClient`, `m_state` is a private variable. Did you make it public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TestCppClient` example is fairly complicated as IB/C++ applications go, but those three lines are important. `m_pReader` is an instance of the `EReader` class, which reads incoming data and produces messages. Because it runs in its own thread, it needs special handling.

The `checkClient` function tells the `EReader` to package incoming data into an `EMessage` and store the message in the message queue. But the application can't access the queue until the `waitForSignal` function returns. Afterward, `processMsgs` reads the `EMessage` and calls the appropriate callback function.

Dealing with the `EReader` is a pain, but once you get an application working, you can copy and paste the code into further applications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just remove all `m_state` switches. you may notice the `ST_` part (start) of `m_state` are ultimately trigged in function `nextValidId()`. In  `processMessages()` function the `ST` conditionals call client functions and afterwards, `m_state` is flipped to `ACK` to then break - only relevant part, if you were to use `processMessages()` for processing msg que is `m_osSignal.waitForSignal(); errno = 0; m_pReader->processMsgs();` which can be called outside of `processMessages()`. Basically when using any function you may comment out all `m_state` switches.  But still need to waitforsignal,process messages as needed. Seems `m_state` was just convenient for the testbed and quickly testing functions only commenting/uncommenting what you wanted to play with.

Answer (score 0):

My .02 many years later...

There is nothing in the TWS C++ api that makes the `*_ACK` values of `m_state` critical, however I find them to be very useful because they flatten and shorten your client class methods. The design of the client app is already complicated enough because state is being changed in random orders in many different places, so this can help quite a bit.

For example, say you keep the sample client code and have a `TestCppClient::processMessages()` implementation as something like this

```
void TestCppClient::processMessages()
{
    switch (m_state ) {
        case ST_REQUESTTICKDATA:
            tickDataOperation();
            break;
        case ST_WAITING_FOR_ENOUGH_DATA:
            break;
        case ST_INITIATING_POSITION:
            initPosition();
            break;
        case ST_INITIATING_POSITION_ACK:
            finishInitiatingPosition();
            break;
    }

    m_osSignal.waitForSignal();
    errno = 0;
    m_pReader->processMsgs();
}
```

This is the core function that gets called over and over again, and all your class methods/callbacks will change `m_state` to control which switch block the first half of this function calls.

Once `m_state` reaches `ST_INITIATING_POSITION`, you'll call `initPosition()`. The definition of `initPosition()` will probably

- send fresh orders, and
- change `m_state` to `ST_INITIATING_POSITION_ACK`

while the definition of `finishInitiatingPosition()` will (probably)

- check to see whether they existing orders to be revised/cancelled, or
- if they've been filled.

All of these different situations will probably involve changing class members, and separating this into two functions will cut down on all the if/else blocks and flatten method definitions. It'll be more manageable to track down bugs and reason about how everything is working.

Finally, I'll mention that knowledge of socket programming or multithreading/synchronization is unnecessary if  all that is being done is reorganizing and implementing class methods.